# How to restructure Android application like shown?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, android-sdk-tools

I would like to restructure my android application that uses a module sdk that sdk is dependent to another google.aar.

[image]

The main app don't have any src directory, instead they have different android applications for internal and external demo purpose.

The lib directory is the main directory for the modules. The ModuleSDK is depends on another `google.aar` AAR file.

now i should able run the CustomerDemoApp & InternalDemoApp depends on the needs. Those two coupled with the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to complete, Its all about the setting.gradle.. we have to play around it. I moved all the files out of app directory to android directory and changed the settings.gradle as follows

`include 'android:app'`
and its working as expected.

Thanks!